# How to get the property defined in @JsonTypeInfo in java code for polymorphic class during deserialization?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have a frequency class which takes a property type which tells the deserializer which subclass to resolve to during the runtime.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = FrequencyIncidence.class, name= "INCIDENCE"),
    @Type(value = FrequencyRange.class, name="RANGE"),
})
public abstract class Frequency extends Audit {

private FrequencyType frequencyType;

public FrequencyType getFrequencyType() {
    return frequencyType;
}

public void setFrequencyType(FrequencyType frequencyType) {
    this.frequencyType = frequencyType;
}
```

Is there any way I can access the property type in my java code so I don't have to define another field frequencyType in my java class?
Right now I need the frequencyType field to determine the subclass in java code and populate the  data in database in java service class. The json for my frequency looks like this.

> {"frequency": {
>                "type":"INCIDENCE",
>                "frequencyType":"INCIDENCE" }}

type is used for providing metadata information to json deserializer and frequencyType is used to determine which subclass information we are sending.
Can we condense it to just one property instead of two?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure Jackson to not remove the `type` field during deserialization. You achieve this by setting the [visible](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html#visible()) parameter. As the docs in the link say:

> defines whether type identifier value will be passed as part of JSON stream to deserializer (true), or handled and removed by TypeDeserializer (false)

and

> Default value is false, meaning that Jackson handles and removes the type identifier from JSON content

Configure `@JsonTypeInfo` like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type",
    visible = true)
```

and make sure there is a setter named `setType` in your class that Jackson will invoke during deserialization with the type JSON field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. You need two things:

1 - First you need to change the `visible` property in `@JsonTypeInfo`. That will allow to keep the "type" value for deserialization.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type",
    visible = true)
```

2 - And after you need that the field in Frequency has the same name as the type property.

```
public abstract class Frequency {

   private FrequencyType type;

   public FrequencyType getType() {
       return type;
   }

   public void setType(FrequencyType type) {
       this.type = type;
   }
```

And that is it, after that you can send `{"type":"INCIDENCE"}` and the Java object will have type = INCIDENCE.